# pseudoinverse of a square block diagonal matrix with projected diagonal matirces on diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, orthogonality, projection-matrices

Consider the following block-diagonal matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
P \Sigma P & 0\\
0 & (I-P) \Sigma (I-P)
\end{pmatrix}

Where $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix, and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix. The individual diagonal elements $P \Sigma P$ and $(I-P) \Sigma (I-P)$ are generally not invertible (unless P doesn't reduce the rank), however, the entire matrix seems to be invertible (validated numerically). Is there a simple expression for its inverse?

Update: @Carl_Schildkraut has shown the matrix is not invertible. Is there a simple expression for the pseudo inverse?

Comment: If this matrix is invertible, then both of the diagonal blocks are invertible since the blocks represent restrictions of your matrix to an invariant subspace.

Answer (score 5):

A block matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}$$
with $A$ and $B$ square is invertible if and only if $A$ and $B$ are invertible -- otherwise, the rank is less than full (alternatively, its determinant is $\det(A)\det(B)$, which is $0$ if one of $A$ or $B$ fails to be invertible). Its inverse is
$$\begin{pmatrix}A^{-1}&0\\0&B^{-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
However, in your example, it is impossible for both components to be invertible. This would require both $P$ and $I-P$ to be invertible, which means that $P$ cannot have an eigenvalue of $0$ or $1$. However, these are the only possible eigenvalues of a projection matrix!

Comment: Thanks! As an alternative, is there a simplified expression for the pseudoinverse?

Comment: @user1767774 I'm unfortunately not that familiar with pseudoinverses, so I'm not sure. My first guess would be that $P\Sigma^{-1}P$ may do the trick (for the top left block matrix; for the bottom right it would be the same with $P$ replaced by $I-P$), but I'm having trouble verifying the necessary conditions. (Update: it's not correct.)